# Python TypeError: encoding with 'cp1252' codec failed

Tags: python, encoding, cp1252

I get this error when I run any installation command:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\TOSHIB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-hztbm9lf\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])]
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 971, in run_command
        log.info("running %s", command)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\log.py", line 44, in info
        self._log(INFO, msg, args)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\log.py", line 33, in _log
        msg = msg.encode(encoding, "backslashreplace").decode(encoding)
    TypeError: encoding with 'cp1252' codec failed (TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable)
```

The installation command in this case is

> pip install git+https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM

What am I doing wrong?

I am on python 3.4.2, on pip 10.0.1 and on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you show your code which led to the error? And tell us what platform you are on? `cp1252` sounds like a Windows encoding,

Comment: Yes im on windows, i forgot to mention it. but this the installation command that i was execiting pip install git+https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can download the wheel package of pyfm from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyfm

Just run the wheel package as python install .whl let me know the result

Comment: It worked, so everytime i need to install something, i need to download its wheel package ?

Comment: Its safer. Github is a Version control system, and pip install git ... will pull the latest version, not necessarily a working version. wheels on PyPi are generally tested, and you get these surprises far less often. It gets interesting though when you don't have pip like in 3.2.1, my Portable version...

Comment: Not necessarily, if it fails with pip install do it with wheel package